# Unable to Communicate from one azure VM in same virtual net to the secondary NIC of another azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have an azure Linux VM say VM1 having only one network interface with private IP `10.3.0.5`, I have another azure Linux VM say VM2 with two network interfaces, the private IP on primary network interface is `10.3.5.4`, the private IP on the secondary network interface is `10.3.4.4`.
Now I am able to ping VM2 from VM1 on primary network interface of VM2 as 
`ping 10.3.5.4` but I am not able to ping it in on secondary network interface as ping `10.3.4.4`.

After reading azure docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics#configure-guest-os-for-multiple-nics, they say that you would have to manually add required routes to achieve this.

Similar problem in windows VM - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4048050/troubleshooter-for-azure-vm-connectivity-problems

here is the result of command `route -n` on VM2

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.5.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.3.4.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.3.5.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.3.5.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.3.5.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
```

Now as per the above azure docs, it is missing an entry something like this

```
0.0.0.0        10.3.4.1         0.0.0.0        UG     0      0        0  eth1
```

I tried adding this route to my VM2 but after running the following command, my vm just stopped responding
`route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 10.3.4.1 dev eth1`

How do I add the correct route for my problem ? Please help !

Comment: Your route adding seems correct, or try to use a command `ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.3.4.1 dev eth1` following [this](https://www.cloudibee.com/static-route-linux/).?

Comment: After running your command it says ```RTNETLINK answers: File exists```

Comment: Can you restart your networking service depending on your Linux system? for example, run `service network restart` from my sharing link.

Comment: Failed to restart network.service: Unit network.service not found
instead i did ```sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth1```
that removed the entry we added.

Comment: Cross posted: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0714756b-2a69-4d45-b57d-52b38f58acb7/unable-to-communicate-from-one-azure-vm-in-same-virtual-net-to-the-secondary-nic-of-another-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: I only asked that question there as I am getting no help here.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is adding another network interface to your VM1. For example, I have VMA with two network interfaces. The private IP of the primary network interface is `10.0.3.4`.The private IP on the secondary network interface is `10.0.2.5`.

Result of command route -n on VMA

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Ifac
0.0.0.0         10.0.3.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.0.3.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.0.3.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
```

The VMB also has two network interfaces.The private IP of the primary network interface is `10.0.1.4`.The private IP on the secondary network interface is `10.0.2.4`. The private IP `10.0.2.4` of VMB and private IP `10.0.2.5` are in the same subnet.

Result of command route -n on VMB

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Ifa
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth
168.63.129.16   10.0.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth
169.254.169.254 10.0.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth
```

So in the VMA, I can ping `10.0.1.4` through the primary network interface and ping `10.0.2.4` through the secondary network interface.